# PolynomialFeatures Sklearn (many parameters)

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Here is my code.

```
 import numpy as np
 from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
 from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
 X=np.array([[1, 2, 4]]).T
 print(X)
 y=np.array([1, 4, 16])
 print(y)
 X_poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2).fit_transform(X)
 print(X_poly)
 # fit_intercept = False since PolynomialFeatures will create a 0-order   
 polynomial as well.
 model = LinearRegression(fit_intercept = False)
 model.fit(X_poly,y)

print('Coefficients: \n', model.coef_)
print('Others: \n', model.intercept_)
```

Please, how can change this code to use many parameters.
Example of models:

```
y=a*x*x+b * z+ c* t (we have y, x, z and t)
```

Thanks a lot for help.
Kind regards.

Comment: Not clear. Are you talking about multiple features (multiple independent variables, on which the result `y` depends)?

Comment: @VivekKumar yes, that's it. Is this possible using sklearn ? Kind regards. Thnks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use multiple lists in X.

```
X = np.array([[1, 2, 4],
              [2, 3, 9]]).T     #<== Added a second list
print(X)
# Output
feature1  feature2
     1         2
     2         3
     4         9

y = np.array([1, 4, 16])
```

So here your data have two features. Now you can simply use the same code you are using before:

```
X_poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2).fit_transform(data)
print(X_poly)
# Output
[[ 1.  1.  2.  1.  2.  4.]
 [ 1.  2.  3.  4.  6.  9.]
 [ 1.  4.  9. 16. 36. 81.]]


model = LinearRegression(fit_intercept = False)
model.fit(X_poly,y)
print('Coefficients: \n', model.coef_)
# Output
('Coefficients: \n', array([-0.10133796,  0.1456888 , -0.01660059,  0.54831516,  0.45019822,
                            -0.11496531]))

print('Others: \n', model.intercept_)
# Output
('Others: \n', 0.0)
```

Comment: the generated model has the form of y=a*x*x+b*z+c  that's it ?

Comment: X = np.array([[1, 2, 4] 
              [0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0]])         X=x,z,t ? that's it ? please, how can i differenciate between coefficient of each variable ?